# My Next.JS-Redux app compiles 2 page at once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-persist

I got these compiles on terminal after redirecting with window.location.href

```
wait  - compiling /login/verify (client and server)...
wait  - compiling /login (client and server)...
```

It should be goes to /login/verify, but back to /login instead because of it.

Here is my code on redirect:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.authCode == '0')
  {
    // redirect to homepage
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = '/'
    }, 2000)
  } else if(nextProps.authCode == '20') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = '/register/verify'
    }, 2000)
  } else if(nextProps.authCode == '30')
  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = '/login/verify'
    }, 2000)
  } else {
    this.setState({
      alertLoading: false,
      alertFailed: true,
      alertMsg: nextProps.authInfo
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` for redirection.

you can use `router` from `next/router` with the methods `router.replace('/login/verify')` for redirection as well.

I recommend checking this out https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage
for more redirection examples

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, I just found the issue, and I don't know how to handle it. This is the issues:

Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/_devPagesManifest.json due to access control checks.
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/_devMiddlewareManifest.json due to access control checks.
Failed to fetch devPagesManifest
Failed to fetch _devMiddlewareManifest

Comment: it would be good if you can provide more information regarding it.. like steps to reproduce this issue.. 
from my guess.. your issue would be something about your fetch api not working as expected.. can show the code related to your api calling as well? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side#client-side-data-fetching-with-useeffect  I do recommend reading as well for more reference for fetching in nextjs